# How to ssl a network load balancer on port 2022?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, ssl

I am trying to run sftp server [sftpgo](https://github.com/drakkan/sftpgo) on an EC2.

I have the following configuration:

1. ubuntu ec2 machine with a running application(SFPGO) that has GUI run on port 8080 and sftp on port 2022.
2. network load balancer that listen on port 2022 TCP
3. target group register to the ec2 on port 2022 TCP
4. rout53 to give a url the nlb DNS

then if i open filezeila\cyberduck etc I can easily connect using the url I defined on the rout53 but I always get a message `the server's host ke is unknown. You have no guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is`.

for solving it i changed the network load balancer from **TCP to TLS** type on port 2022 and the target group as well ( I use ACM certificate that works on other application load balancers), but then I **can not connect anymore to the server** how should I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SSH (and in turn SFTP) doesn't use TLS, hence TLS load balancer won't work. Use TCP as you did before.
2. When you get that alert in Cyberduck for the first time simply accept it and save it - it should get stored to its *known hosts keys* file and the next time it won't ask again.

   See e.g. here: https://superuser.com/questions/936800/should-i-allow-unknown-host-key-when-using-sftp